# Show angular directives in ckeditor dialog

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I use ckeditor inside of my application. I want to create a dialog window, which can be fully customized using angularjs.

Direct approach does not work. I try to create dialog with single html element as listed below. Angular shows error: controller 'ngInclude', required by directive 'ngInclude', can't be found!

```
54               elements: [
55                 {
56                   type:   'html'
57                   html:   "<div ng-include=\"'/ckeditor/dialogs/wiki_link.html'\"></div>"
58                   onShow: (event) ->
59                   onLoad: (event) ->
60                     $compile(event.sender.parts.dialog.$)($scope)
61                   onHide: (args...) ->
62                     console.log('onHide', args)
63                   setup:  (args...) ->
64                     console.log('setup', args)
65                   commit: (args...) ->
66                     console.log('commit', args)
67                 }
68               ]
```

Actually any alternative will fit.

If I could call angularjs controller method from outside of angular application. It'd work too.

Comment: Actually the question can be extended. For example, what if I need to show html with angularjs markup using jquery ui dialog, which is called outside of my angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Inside of directive, that adds ckeditor to my page I passed scope and $injector to it.

Passing $injector was not obvious. I thought, that angular.injector(['MyApp']) returns the same injector, but it does not. Injector returned by angular.injector(['MyApp']) fails to inject $location or $state. And $templateCache returned by it, was empty, besides page has a lot of templates in script[type=text/ng-template] tags.

Comment: Can you share more information as to how you solved this issue? Maybe some code. How did you get the $compile instance.